# What could stop h2o responding to our R script?

Tags: r, h2o

What are the possible reasons that an h2o service might stop responding to an http REST API request?

We are using the R CRAN package, and after a fair period of time, the h2o server stops responding. We have captured a variety of logs, but there is no obvious error or reason for this. There is also a matter of consistency, which I will detail after the logs. The h2o.logging() log shows:

```
Time:     2019-01-07 11:13:19.262

GET       http://localhost:54321/3/Jobs/$03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_936500deb000be7364a7e2ce61d5451e
postBody:

curlError:         FALSE
curlErrorMessage:
httpStatusCode:    200
httpStatusMessage: OK
millis:            3513

{"__meta":{"data":"removed as it is not relevant"}}

------------------------------------------------------------

Time:     2019-01-07 11:13:25.013

GET       http://localhost:54321/3/Jobs/$03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_936500deb000be7364a7e2ce61d5451e
postBody:

curlError:         TRUE
curlErrorMessage:  Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
httpStatusCode:    -1
httpStatusMessage:
millis:            88616
```

The main log shows it was working just before:

```
Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster:
    H2O cluster uptime:         2 minutes 9 seconds
    H2O cluster timezone:       Etc/UTC
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
    H2O cluster version:        3.20.0.8
    H2O cluster version age:    3 months and 17 days !!!
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_root_ttz747
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1
    H2O cluster total memory:   255.99 GB
    H2O cluster total cores:    2
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  2
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost
    H2O Connection port:        54321
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE
    H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
    R Version:                  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

  |======================================================================| 100%
  |======================================================================| 100%
Error in .h2o.__checkConnectionHealth() :
  H2O connection has been severed. Cannot connect to instance at http://localhost:54321/
Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
Calls: <Anonymous> -> .h2o.__remoteSend -> .h2o.__checkConnectionHealth
```

The interesting thing about this is that it is 100% repeatable on machines that have this problem (the majority), but we also have two machines that don't show this problem (at least don't seem to, we can't rule out they never have, but they usually run it okay).

I've seen that h2o never shuts itself down on its own, so that is unlikely. We stopped any parallelism in the R script, and that didn't change anything.

We therefore need suggestions on how to identify the problem here, and of course fix it.

Comment: Did the java server process die?  Or just get filled up with data and become non-responsive?  I would look at the java process stdout and stderr for clues on what happened.

Comment: @TomKraljevic It appears that the h2o Java process dies. At least it is not running now, and none of the code deliberately stops it. But Rscript deletes all the logs so perhaps something is shutting it down. We modified the script to copy the logs for us at the end, and there is nothing in the .out file that indicates anything is wrong. Indeed, the h2o logs are all captured, and the -error and -fatal logs are empty.

Comment: @TomKraljevic I've done a run on one of the "working" machines, and at the end the h2o server is no longer running, so the R system must be cleaning it up. Thus we can't gain any information from that.

If anyone is able to provide professional help to solve this, please get in touch.

Comment: The company H2O.ai provides enterprise support (i.e. "professional help") for the H2O open source products.  You can contact sales@h2o.ai for more information.

Comment: Did you start H2O from R using `h2o.init()` or from the command line?  If the former, try starting from the command line using `java -jar h2o.jar` or using advanced options detailed here:http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/starting-h2o.html#from-the-command-line

Comment: @ErinLeDell Thanks - I have looked at this, but it doesn't offer any additional "what killed you" control and I'd rather keep it fully script compatible unless otherwise proven. We have done a lot of experiments around this, like different Java's and suchlike.

Comment: @mj2008 although there may not be exactly the switch 'what killed you', h2o.init() runs the H2O server with a couple of options which may result in a different behaviour compared to the run directly from the command line. I suggest to try running it from the command line and see if it works. It may lead us to finding out what has happened.

Comment: @vaclav I did a manual start of the h20 server, and half way through the run it got changed to the one asked for in the R script (CPAN interface). The console got a "killed" log too, for the new one. So far the only machines that have run this okay appear to be physical, unvirtualised, but I just rented a new dedicated server and that fails too.

Comment: @mj2008 How did it get changed? Could you please share the console output when `java -jar h2o.jar` gets executed? Also, could you please share outputs of `uname -a` and `java -version`? When run from the command line, you should also see a line with the location of the logs, something like `Log dir: '/tmp/h2o-vaclav/h2ologs'` . Could you also share the content of that folder (if it contains any non-empty logs). I've run H2O mostly in virtual machines (AWS), that should not be a problem. Finally, what do you mean by "killed log"?

Comment: @vaclav Is there a way I can link up? I've been in touch with support for a paid option, but after a call to the US last night, the UK haven't called me as I was told.
I presume that the R script closed the h2o at some point.

Comment: @mj2008 if you have followup questions about support options and are having trouble getting in contact with folks please feel free to follow up on your original support ticket. But hopefully you were able to get in touch with folks. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. The price of the support was way more than we could afford, but we have done R script changes and that seems to bypass this issue, so looks like we have a way forward. Would have been nice to get to the real heart of the problem.

Comment: @mj2008 thank you for providing an update. If you think you found any solutions that might be helpful to the H2O-3 open source community, it would be great it you could post an answer to your question with you findings. Thanks!

Comment: I am currently facing the same error. I would be interested if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the h2o connection 'open' too many files beyond the default limit set on the machine and that causes the crash.

The limit on open file descriptors can be checked with:

```
ulimit -n
```

And later the soft limit can be modified to a larger valuer:

```
ulimit -Sn 5000
```